# Python: Need to remove first item from list then populate a wx.CheckListBox

Tags: python, list, checklistbox

I am currently working on a python script to analyze SNMP data.  I have a function that reads in a csv file and displays the headers in CheckBoxes organized in a CheckListBox.  I would like to remove the first item, but doing so makes it so my CheckListBox does not populate and I cannot figure out why.  Here is the code:

```
#Generates CheckBoxList with fields from csv (first row)
def onSNMPGen(self,e):
    #reads in first row of csv file; this snmpPaths[0] will likely cause issues with multiple paths -- fix later
    listItems = []
    print "*** Reading in ", self.snmpPaths[0], "....."
    with open(self.snmpPaths[0], 'r') as f: #remember to close csv
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        print "*** Populating Fields ..... "
        for row in reader:
            #Inserts each field into CheckListBox as an item;
            #self.SNMPCheckListBox.InsertItems(row,0)
            listItems.append(row)
            break
        f.close()
    #Need to remove 'Time' (first item) from listItems
    #listItems.pop(0) # this makes it so my CheckListBox does not populate
    #del listItems[0] # this makes it so my CheckListBox does not populate
    for key in listItems:
        self.SNMPCheckListBox.InsertItems(key,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for row in reader:
            #Inserts each field into CheckListBox as an item;
            #self.SNMPCheckListBox.InsertItems(row,0)
            listItems.append(row)
            break
```

Because you've used break, your list only will have one item. So when you remove that item there is nothing to populate your CheckListBox with.

If you're 100% sure it's the first item then you can rewrite your loop like:

```
 for row in reader[1:]:
            #Inserts each field into CheckListBox as an item;
            #self.SNMPCheckListBox.InsertItems(row,0)
            listItems.append(row)
```

reader[1:] means you're only going to add second items onwards in your listItems list.

Comment: Ok I see that now. The way the rest of my script works, that fix will cause other problems. Perhaps I want to parse through the one item in my list and remove it that way, or find a way to ignore/remove the first column of the csv file

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I was storing my csv row as one item, not multiple items.  I have come up with a fix that i will post

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to roxan I was able to fix my problem after seeing my error.  I was storing the csv row as one item in the list, rather than have each column of the row being an item.  Here is my fix:

```
#Generates CheckBoxList with fields from csv (first row)
def onSNMPGen(self,e):
    #reads in first row of csv file; this snmpPaths[0] will likely cause issues with multiple paths -- fix later
    listItems = []
    print "*** Reading in ", self.snmpPaths[0], "....."
    with open(self.snmpPaths[0], 'r') as f: #remember to close csv
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        print "*** Populating Fields ..... "
        for row in reader:
            listItems = row             break
        f.close()
    del listItems[0] #Time is always first item so this removes it
    self.SNMPCheckListBox.InsertItems(listItems,0)
```